# GET request with redirect URL could not get 302 in JAVA but Postman works well

Tags: java, postman, okta-api

Here is an OKTA API call: GET {{OAuthProviderUrl}}/oauth2/v1/authorize?client_id={{clientId}}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope={{scopes}}&state={{state}}&sessionToken={{sessionToken}}&redirect_uri={{redirectUri}}

It can return code: 302 with a "location" header by using Postman, but...
when I tried to implement the call in JAVA as:

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setRedirectsEnabled(true).build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
String location = null;
HttpResponse response;
try {
response = httpClient.execute((new HttpGet(URL));
responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It always returns code: 400. Is there any different flow between postman and JAVA? Thanks.

The GET queries do not have difference from postman to Java implementation.

Comment: You have enabled redirects, so I'm guessing the URL at the location from the header returns the 400.

Comment: Please add the url value to the question. Sensitive data masked if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out the `setRedirectsEnabled`. It will cause the httpclient to follow the redirects rather than pass the first response back to you. The redirected-to page could be returning the 400.

We can get more clarity on the cause of the issue by printing the response body:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println("Response body: " + responseBody);
```

If that does not fix then it’s probably a problem with the parameters being sent from Java, resulting in the auth failing and the call returning a 400. That is pretty much the textbook definition of a 400.

The correct way to add parameters is like [this](https://www.baeldung.com/apache-httpclient-parameters)

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder(“https://provider.com/oauth2/v1/authorize”)
  .addParameter("client_id", "value1")
  .addParameter("response_type", "value2")
  // etc
  .build();
```

I find it very useful to fire httpclient calls to https://httpbin.org/get and then printing the response body as I suggest above. httpbin.org echoes what is sent allowing a comparison with postman (if you fire a call you know works to httpbin.)